# Postgresql why can't login with newly created user?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using phppgadmin, connecting with `olduser` - works fine. But when i create a new user `newuser` - i cant login with it.

*pgbounce.log:*

```
(nodb)/(nouser)@unix:5432 closing because: No such user: newuser (age=0)
(nodb)/(nouser)@unix:5432 Pooler Error: No such user: newuser
(nodb)/(nouser)@unix:5432 login failed: db=template1 user=newuser
```

But user `newuser` exists in database - i see it when i login as `olduser`, also if i make a sql like "select * from pg_shadow;" i see all my users and `newuser` also as `olduser` have same parameters.

I tryed to make more users with use of "createuser ... " still cant login with them.

*pg_hba.conf:*

```
local   all         postgres                          ident
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

postgresql version 8.4

Comment: Please try connecting directly with `psql` and verify that works.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using pgbouncer, you probably need to add the user to user_list.txt.